# The good and the bad turtles: how to update theirs actions?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to build a network with good and bad turtles, in order to study their actions (do-well, do-wrong, do-nothing). 
Good turtles may be susceptible, infected, or selfish; bad turtles only infected, instead. 
At each tick, other turtles (goods and bad) are created. When the simulation starts, each turtle can (randomly) decide to do something good, bad or just nothing based on its neighbours.

My approach to write the part of code regarding the turtles' actions is the following:

1. check the links of a random chosen turtle G;
2. if the turtle has no links, then it can choose between do-good or do-nothing; otherwise, if it has at least one link, then we need to check if its neighbors are good or bad turtles in order to decide which action the turtle should take. 
   The turtle has to choose if follows a good or bad turtle and do some action (do-well, do-wrong, or do-nothing).
3. if the turtle's neighbour is good (this means not infected), the actions to choose with a certain probability can be do-well, do-wrong or do-nothing. The turtle will continue to be good.
4. if the turtle's neighbour is bad (this means infected), the actions to choose will be a certain probability can be do-well, do-wrong or do-nothing. The turtle will become infected, only if it chooses do-wrong.

This is the part of code that I have written trying to answer this question:

```
    ifelse one-of goods with [any? link-neighbors]  ;; check neighbours and decide action to take
     [ ifelse out-link-neighbors with [infected? true] ;; if neighbor is infected, it should have three options: do-well, do-wrong, do-nothing.
        [ 
           ifelse random-float 1 < probability
           [do-well][do-wrong]
        ] ;; but there should be another possible action, do-nothing... and maybe I should use an if condition with probability split in 0.3, 0.4, 0.3 for example
      [
        ifelse random-float 1 < probability ;; this if condition is for turtle linked with only good turtles 
            [do-well][do-nothing]
]

 ] [ifelse random-float 1 < probability [do-well][do-nothing]]
```

but I understand that this code cannot work due to errors, so I would like to ask you what I am doing wrong and, eventually, if you could explain me why.

*(If you need to edit the probability, in order to show me how I could set three different options/actions in an if/ifelse condition, please do that. I used probability as an example on what I am trying to do)*

Comment: Hi JenB. I just updated the code with what I have done. Unfortunately, the code is not working, and I am pretty sure that what I have written contains a lot of programming mistakes. I have tried to think on what you suggested and I tried to include your suggestions and advices into the updated code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not understanding what you mean in pints (4) and (5).  About the others, I tried to implement in the code what you suggested, but maybe not correctly. (1) the options are: do-well, do-nothing and do-wrong; 2) I added an if else condition: ifelse random-float 1< probability [][]; 3) I added another if condition to check its neighbors (but it does not work)

Comment: Hi JenB, I am really sorry about this misunderstanding. I tried to change something in my request, in order to be a bit clear about my difficulties and about what I tried to do to answer my questions. I know that I am doing some mistakes, but I would like to try to understand how I could implement my approach. I thought in terms of decision trees, step by step, trying to figure out the possible solution for this part of code. But if someone could tell me what it is wrong and how I could fix it, it would be greatly appreciated it. Thank you for your time and help that you are providing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of problems.

- `ifelse one-of goods with [any? link-neighbors]` makes no sense. Your description says that you want to choose a random turtle. This doesn't choose a turtle, it checks whether a random turtle has any neighbours. But it doesn't then use that same turtle for any of the code that follows.
- Your description has a logic problem at step 2. What happens if the chosen turtle has two neighbours - one good and one bad? The way I have written the code below gets the turtle to randomly select one of its neighbours and then check whether that particular neighbour is good or bad. But you could also check whether there are any that are bad, the proportion of bad is above some threshold, or all are bad. You need to decide the implementation that you want.
- If there are three possible actions, then you need some way of indicating the probability of each, you can't just use one probability.

So I made some guesses and here's one possibility. Of course, it is untested as I haven't built a model with 'goods' or a network etc. Hopefully it will help you work out what you want and how to do it.

```
ask one-of goods ; select a random turtle
[ ifelse [any? link-neighbors]  ; check if it has neighbours
  [ let choice one-of out-link-neighbors   ; pick one of the available neighbours
    [ let roll random-float 1     ; get a random number
      ifelse  [infected?] of choice
      ; condition if the chosen neighbour is infected
      [ ifelse roll < probability1
        [ do-well ]
        [ ifelse roll < probability1 + probability2 [do-wrong] [do-nothing] ]
      ]
      ; condition if the chosen neigbour not infected 
      [ ifelse roll < probability1   
        [do-well]
        [do-nothing]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [ print "No neighbours to select" ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, JenB, for your comments. Yes, absolutely you are right! The condition ifelse one-of goods with [any? link-neighbors] does not check if a good turtle has or not neighbors, but it selects randomly one good turtle with at least one link. My apologies! However, I got an error from this condition, just copying and pasting because it expects a true/false. Furthermore,I did not think about using more probabilities, so thank you for letting me know about it.

Comment: I would have a further question related to the decision-making of the turtles and an 'agenda' to build in order to take into consideration their actions. If I declare a variable (agenda), and initialise it within the setup/go as set agenda [], could I add elements to this list, by considering the different taken options (well, wrong, nothing)?E.g.:  `ifelse roll < probability1
        [ do-well set agenda lput well agenda ]`. At each tick, each turtle takes different decisions and has its own agenda made by well, wrong and/or nothing. If not appropriate, I will delete the comment. Thanks

Comment: Try it out and see. But yes, this code looks like it should work. Try putting print statements before and after so you can check it does what you expect.

Comment: Update: I added agenda in `goods-own` and added `ask goods [set agenda [] ]` in `setup`. Then,  I added in `do-well/wrong/nothing set well/wrong/nothing 1`, in order to update the agenda depending on the chosen action. Finally, I added it in the `ifelse` for deciding the actions to take as, e.g., `[do-well set agenda lput well agenda]`. It does not give me an error. But unfortunately it seems to leave the list empty ...

Comment: New question required. Please actually look at the information about how to ask a question. The question needs to be specific - only one problem. Show only the relevant code. Describe the specific problem (such as the error message you get and which line, or the behaviour you get and the behaviour you expect). This is no longer anything to do with the question above.

Comment: If I add a condition like ` set infected? true in the last part of code, ` if [infected?] of choice                                   ;; condition to check if the chosen neighbor is infected
            [become-infected]
        ] `,   I turtles does not change color properly (` to become-infected set color red end `). Could you please tell me why?